# Why cannot I use variable in for loop of tikzmath?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a batch of circles using the following code. However, I failed to create the figure i want. and i got a error saying `undefined control sequence. argument 0,...,\NY`. But if i change `\NY` to `4`. it works well. Why cannot i use \NY in the `{0,...,\NY}`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    \VX = 30;
    \VY = 30;
    int \NX = 6;
    int \NY = 4;
    int \nix; int \niy;
    \OX = 0; \OY = 0;
    for \niy in {0,...,\NY}{%
      for \nix in {0,...,6}{%
        {\node [circle, draw = red, minimum size = \VX pt] at (\nix*\VX pt,\niy*\VY pt) {};};
      };
    };
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things like

```
int \NY = 4;
```

are not allowed. Use

```
int \NY; \NY = 4;
```

instead and your MWE will work:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    \VX = 30;
    \VY = 30;
    int \NX; \NX = 6;
    int \NY; \NY = 4;
    int \nix; int \niy;
    \OX = 0; \OY = 0;
    for \niy in {0,...,\NY}{%
      for \nix in {0,...,\NX}{%
        {\node [circle, draw = red, minimum size = \VX pt] at (\nix*\VX pt,\niy*\VY pt) {};};
      };
    };
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could use `\newcommand\NX{6}` `\newcommand\NY{4}` in the preamble, then you could use them also in the loop.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\newcommand\NX{6}
\newcommand\NY{4}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzmath{
    \VX = 30;
    \VY = 30;
    int \nix; int \niy;
    \OX = 0; \OY = 0;
    for \niy in {0,...,\NY}{%
      for \nix in {0,...,\NX}{%
        {\node [circle, draw = red, minimum size = \VX pt] at (\nix*\VX pt,\niy*\VY pt) {};};
      };
    };
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```